# Display login validation errors on bootstrap modal pop up not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap modal dialog for login popup, having trouble displaying errors on label placed on modal dialog. Everything works great, controller gets called and validate the user credentials. The issue comes while sending json response message back from controller, Instead of displaying error on modal dialog it redirects to blank page and displays json error on top. please advise or suggest. 
please don't send me duplicate questions link I already researched a lot. check the given code and see whats wrong.

Partial View : _signIn.cshtml

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signInModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="signInModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" 
 data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
          <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- Row -->
            <div class="row">
                <h4>
                    <p class="text-xs-center">
                        Sign in to Photolab
                    </p>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <p class="text-xs-center">
                <span class="pi-or">or use your email address</span>
            </p>

            @using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateUser", "Account",  
 FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "signInForm" }))
            {

                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">

                        <div class="modalbox">

                            <p>
                                <label id="lblMessage" class="small"></label>
                            </p>

                            <!-- Email form -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "form-control form-control-round", @required = "required", @placeholder = "Email address", id = "signInEmail" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
                            </div>
                            <!-- End email form -->
                            <!-- Password form -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control form-control-round", @type = "Password", @placeholder = "Password", @required = "required" })
                            </div>
                            <!-- End password form -->

                            <p class="pull-right small">
                                <a href="#" id="forgotModal">
                                    Forgot password?
                                </a>
                            </p>

                            <div class="checkbox pull-left">
                                <label class="small">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.RememberMe)Remember Me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Submit button -->
                            <div class="form-group-btn">
                                <button type="submit" id="btnSignIn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                                    Sign In
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End submit button -->

                        </div>
                        <!-- End box -->
                    </div>

                </div>

            }
            <!-- End row -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <p class="text-xs-center">
            Don't have Account? <a href="#" id="btnSignUp" class="flipLink">Sign Up</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery :

```
<script>
$(function () {

    $('#btnSignIn').click(function () {

        var url = '@Url.Action("ValidateUser", "Account")';
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache:false,
            url: url,
            datatype:'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
              if (result.success != true) {
                    lert(result.response);
                    $("#lblMessage").text("");
                    $("#lblMessage").append(result.response);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(result.response);
                    window.location.href = result.response;
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

MVC AccountController.cs

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ValidateUser(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        var result = new { success = "false", response = "Error Message" };

        try
        {
            var loginResult = _customerRegistrationService.ValidateCustomer(model.UserName, model.Password);

            switch (loginResult)
            {
                case LoginResult.Successful:
                    {
                        //_authenticationService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.Password, true);

                        ImplementFormsAuthentication(model.UserName);

                        result = new { success = "true", response = Url.Action("Listings", "Listing") };

                        return RedirectToAction("Listings", "Listing");

                        //break;

                    }
                case LoginResult.NotRegistred:

                    result = new { success = "false", response = "The user name or password provided is incorrect" };
                    break;
                case LoginResult.WrongPassword:
                    result = new { success = "false", response = "Incorrect Password" };
                    break;

                default:
                    result = new { success = "false", response = "Invalid username/password" };
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
 <li class="nav-item">
      <a href='#' id="btnLogin" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signInModal">                                                    Login
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using button type submit. so It is redirecting to a blank page.
Use button type button so it will not post form to blank page.

```
<button type="button" id="btnSignIn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
       Sign In
</button>
```